# What does exactly mean if an Azure template says "Bring Your Own License enabled"?

Tags: azure, syncfusion

**Context**

When I try to create a new Compute resource and picking it in Azure portal Marketplace the description starts with "Bring Your Own License enabled" I suppose the Compute resource will be a Windows Server with IIS configured and a web application installed.

**Question**

What does "Bring Your Own License enabled" in this context exactly mean?

- a) I must have MS licences for the the Windows Server, that is
  **not** included in the Azure pricing.
- b) I have an option to use my own licences. If I do not use them, the
  price is what I see, and if I    configure to use them the price is
  lowered (sounds a bit unrealistic)

Bottom line: If I would like to use this resource do I have to own an MS license a) or not b)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to license software on hardware provisioned through the Azure marketplace.

The first is an "embedded" license. This means that when you start up a templated compute resource (in your case a VM with Syncfusion), you don't need to buy an additional license for Syncfusion. You will notice that the usage cost for the VM is inflated compared to a vanilla VM without the software installed on it. The cost of the license is baked into the price you pay to "rent" the VM from Microsoft via Azure subscription.

The second is "Bring your own license". This is typically used when an organisation has existing software licenses already purchased (in this case, for Syncfusion). When you bring your own license, you only pay for the vanilla virtual machine and apply your pre-bough Syncfusion license. In other words, the cost of the syncfusion license is not built in to the rental of the virtual machine.

This can get more complex when you factor in templates with multiple software packages installed but hopefully you get the drift.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Do I understand correctly, that the Microsoft Licenses are always "embedded" to the price of the Azure resource, and we talking about only the 3rd party software, this case Syncfusion?

Comment: VMs stood up on Azure as part of services (e.g. batch pools, ASEs etc) all include the OS license. VMs supplied by Microsoft stood up from the Azure Marketplace have both embedded and BYOL skus (http://scug.be/wim/2017/04/24/azure-iaas-built-a-vm-from-a-bring-your-own-license-byol-image-with-azure-powershell/). Third Parties creating VM templates can provision the OS licence embedded or BYOL (Bring your own license).